# Extrair dados de uma web levar para Excel

Tags: vba

Estou tentando extrair dados de cotações do seguinte site: https://bancdebinary.com/es/

Para isso estou tentando usar o código fonte do site. O problema é que não consigo localizar no codigo fonte as informaçoes que preciso, como ser a cotação do euro frente ao dollar.

Vocês podem me passar uma dica?

Comment: você poderia mostrar o que você já tentou? O que significa que você tentou utilizar o código do site? Existe algum exemplo em VBA no site? Se existe, você poderia mostrar o link?

Comment: Eu tente usar o exemplo disponivel no seguinte link: 
http://scriptorium.serve-it.nl/view.php?sid=40

O problema é que nõ codigo fonte não aparece a informação das cotaçoes.

Comment: sua pergunta falta detalhes. Se você postasse a parte do código onde você interpreta o HTML do site já ajudaria, além, é claro, de mostrar em uma imagem o que você está tentando obter do site, ou seja, um print-screen mostrando exatamente onde está a cotação. De qualquer maneira, como se trata de dados de Cotação, você já viu isso: https://openexchangerates.org/ . Pelo que pude analisar do HTML do site, você terá trabalho pra poder interpretá-lo com VBA somente. A solução do site acima parece bem interessante e fácil de usar, trata-se de uma API em JSON.

Comment: O openexchangerates.org possui uma opção free: (https://openexchangerates.org/signup/free). Com essa opção você pode fazer 1000 requsições de cotação por mês. Caso você precise de mais, então é preciso pagar.

Comment: Cantoni, 

Obrigado pelas suas respostas.
Em realidade eu preciso extrair uma cotação a cada 60 segundos.